# RxJs take last if completed, otherwise insert delay between values

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I will give full explanation, but basically I need to ensure that

1. there is some delay between emitted values
2. if the observable is completed, just return latest value.

### GIVEN THAN

I have two observables, that each emit 0 or 1 values and then complete:

```
 //1. lazy observable that emit 0 or two value created at time of subscription and then completes
 const cache$ = this.getFromCacheLazy();

 //2.  ReplaySubject, that emits value in 1-1500ms and completes
 const request$ = this.executeRequest();
```

I combined it to observable, that first emit cache value (if any) and then requested value:

```
 const cacheAndRequest$ = concat(cache$, request$);
```

And I subscribe to it some time later:

```
 setTimeout(() => {
     cacheAndRequest$.Subscribe(console.log);
 }, someDelay)
```

### HOW DO I

modify or pipe `cacheAndRequest$`, so that:

1. if `$request` is already completed at the time of subscription,
   `cache$` value must be ignored.

   - *hint: if $request is completed*, also cacheAndRequest$ is completed at the time of subscription.
2. if `$request` is NOT completed at the time of subscription, emit value from $cache immediately and value from $request earliest 500ms later. In other words, there must be a delay between those two values.

Here is playground:

Copy [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Liero/snippets/master/rxviz-sample1.js) code [here](https://rxviz.com/)

Comment: It's an interesting question. I'll have to think about it for a bit. I think the main issue is that `concat()` will not help you with `request$` already being completed. You'll need to `forkJoin()` or `combineLatest()`, although the last creation operator will prevent any emitted values untill the `request$` gives you something. I'd say you will need to `merge()` and give both streams a `startWith()` so there's a base value to work with. I'm not sure if there's a RxJS valid way to check if one of the streams has already completed.

Comment: The `combineLatest` where the `stream` has a `startWith()` will allow you to determine a sort of state. It'll give you like `[value, 0]` or something; and when you're going to `complete()` the `stream` you send another value like `1` and you'll get `[value, 1]` and be able to determine the difference in your logic.

Comment: Another thought in regards to your delaying depending on the state internally of your Observable. You could `switchMap()` after and create a disposable Observable inside there. Depending on the determined state, you could return `of(value)` or `of(value).pipe(delay(500))` etcetera. It's a bit complicated to explain, but it'll result in a well readable stream.

Comment: Give me a ping (here or on Twitter) if you've updated the question. I tink it's an interesting question, I'd be happy to take a look and play around with your playground.

Comment: I've updated it, see last line. Let's remove comments, afterwards. Hint: I think the requirement #1 could be solved by debounceTime(0), since merges 2 values into 1, if response is ready

Comment: The biggest issue us that you're expecting `$request` to do anything before you subscribe to it which is not how Observables work. So it looks like you should use intermediate ReplaySubject that for example subscribes to `$request` immediatelly.

Comment: Can you explain the business problem please. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Reactgular: Yeah, in SPA app, I do request REST API, but I also want to display cached values first (that is the concat). Besides that, there is some application event, that tells that the app is ready to display some data (that is the timeout here). It doesn't make sense to display cached data, when I already have response from API when the application event occurs. And the delay between cached data and response data emits is needed for some other IE workaround

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, I modified a little bit your `cache$` and `request$` to identify the observable:

```
const cache$ = getFromCacheLazy().pipe(
  map(cache => {
    return {source: 'cache', value: cache};
  })
);

const request$ = executeRequest().pipe(
  map(request => {
    return {source: 'request', value: request};
  })
);
```

I left the `concat` as you did.

And Then I applied the `withLatestFrom` function to get the latest emitted value. If the latest emitted value come from `request$`I return it, else I concatenate observables to return the `cache$` value and wait at least 500ms to emit the `request$`:

```
const $subscribeDelayed = timer(subscriptionDelay)
  .pipe(
    withLatestFrom(cacheAndRequest$), // Provide the latest value from cacheAndRequest$
    switchMap(res => {
      // if request$ is already completed at the time of subscription, cache$ value is ignored
      // else cache$ is emitted and request$ is emitted after at least 500ms
      return res[1].source === 'request'
        ? of(res[1].value)
        : concat(
          of(res[1].value),
          request$.pipe(
            delay(500),
            map(res => res.value)
          )
        );
    }),
    tap(res => console.log(res)),
  );
```

See [my working example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pynjmu?file=index.ts).

Comment: Not bad at all. Actually it is quite straightforward. However I was able to solve #2 with `debounceTime(0)`, which prevents cache and response being emmited at the same time, when observable is completed at the time of subscription. It works, because $cache always emits and completes at the time of subscription